# Does synchronized affect object members?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, synchronized

If I call a object synchronized, can I access objects inside that object as if they were synchronized? Or can I only access the data types?

Comment: Your question is very vague - what do you mean by "call a object synchronized"? It would really help if you'd give a specific code example.

Answer (score 1):

Even though your goal is to protect data, synchronization provides exclusivity around a block of code, not a piece of data. Code outside the synchronization blocks (or in blocks that use different objects), may alter the data you are trying to protect even if that isn't what you want.

Any correct locking strategy must ensure that blocks of code that could interfere with each other hold the same lock.  That includes code which could interfere with another copy of itself run in a second thread.

```
synchronized (myObject) {
  // sensitive code
}
```

Locking at the method level is just a shorthand for locking the `this` pointer for the body of the method. (Or the `class` object for a static method).

Answer (score 0):

Possibly, but only with care. You can do this if you always lock the same object.

Most likely you have to lock each object.

Answer (score 0):

The ability to `synchronize` on every object is a commonly cited annoyance in Java because it's confusing.

Basically, all it means is that every object can be a lock. That's it. Hence, there is no special effect on object's members when you lock on the parent object and it doesn't matter which particular object you use as a lock. If all your thread locks on the same object, only one of them will be running/accessing whatever code is in the synchronized block. If some of them don't, there is no such guarantee.

If you want to make sure only one thread is accessing a member at any given time, make sure all threads that access that member lock (or "synchronize") on the same object before accessing it. As long as you do that, it doesn't matter which object you use for the lock.